# How to make wait async task for result for further operation xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, async-await

In my Xamarin.Forms Application, I am using azure mobile service for Offline-data sync.

in my App's OnStart method I am calling an async task and according to the result of the task I need to load differrent pages. Unfortunately now no page is loading. When I remove the call to async task the page is loading.

OnStart Method

```
protected async override void OnStart()
{
    login = new List<Login>();
    List<Login> items = await App.dataManager.GetLoginAsync();

    if (items.Count <= 0)
    {
        MainPage = (new Registration());
    }
    else
    {
        MainPage = (new LoginPage());
    }
}
```

Async Task Method

```
public async Task<List<Login>> GetLoginAsync()
{
    try
    {   
        IEnumerable<Login> items = await logins
            .ToEnumerableAsync();
        return new List<Login>(items);
    }
    catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"Invalid sync operation: {0}", msioe.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"Sync error: {0}", e.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: _The MainPage property should be set in the App constructor:_ (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#mainpage-property)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#mainpage-property]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [The MainPage property should be set in the App constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#mainpage-property), and we should not block UI thread by waiting an async method in constructor, you can achieve your navigation logic like this:

In App's constructor set MainPage like this:

```
MainPage = new StarterPage();
```

In StarterPage's OnAppearing method:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    login = new List<Login>();

    //show ActivityIndicator

    List<Login> items = await App.dataManager.GetLoginAsync();

    //hide ActivityIndicator

    if (items.Count <= 0)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(Registration);
    }
    else
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(LoginPage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Async operations typically blocks the UI thread. You may use `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
  MainPage = (new Registration());
});`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `OnStart` method doesn't really work well with `async void`.

What you can do:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    NavigateToEntryAsync()
        .ContinueWith(
            t => Log.Error("Unhandled exception while navigation to entry page", t.Exception.InnerException), 
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}

protected async Task NavigateToEntryAsync()
{
    login = new List<Login>();
    List<Login> items = await App.dataManager.GetLoginAsync();

    if (items.Count <= 0)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => MainPage = (new Registration()));
    }
    else
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => MainPage = (new LoginPage()));
    }
}
```